# Parquet Writer to buffer or byte stream

Tags: java, bufferedreader, parquet

I have a java application that converts json messages to parquet format. Is there any parquet writer which writes to buffer or byte stream in java? Most of the examples, I have seen write to files.

Answer (score 5):

TLDR; you will need to implement `OutputFile`, e.g. something along the line of:

```
import org.apache.parquet.io.OutputFile;
import org.apache.parquet.io.PositionOutputStream;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ParquetBufferedWriter implements OutputFile {

    private final BufferedOutputStream out;

    public ParquetBufferedWriter(BufferedOutputStream out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public PositionOutputStream create(long blockSizeHint) throws IOException {
        return createPositionOutputstream();
    }

    private PositionOutputStream createPositionOutputstream() {
        return new PositionOutputStream() {
            @Override
            public long getPos() throws IOException {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                out.write(b);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public PositionOutputStream createOrOverwrite(long blockSizeHint) throws IOException {
        return createPositionOutputstream();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsBlockSize() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public long defaultBlockSize() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

And your writer would be something like:

```
    ParquetBufferedWriter out = new ParquetBufferedWriter();
        try (ParquetWriter<Record> writer = AvroParquetWriter.
                <Record>builder(out)
                .withRowGroupSize(DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE)
                .withPageSize(DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
                .withSchema(SCHEMA)
                .build()) {

            for (Record record : records) {
                writer.write(record);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
```

Comment: position (getPos()) should not be 0, otherwise output is broken. Correct answer is by: @breadcrumb42 with counting bytes for position. Other solution could be use: CountingOutpustream and set position based on position of the OutputStream.

Answer (score 4):

I just also needed to write to a stream, so I completed the example given by naimdjon. The following works perfectly fine for me.

```java
class ParquetBufferedWriter implements OutputFile {
    
    private final BufferedOutputStream out;

    public ParquetBufferedWriter(BufferedOutputStream out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public PositionOutputStream create(long blockSizeHint) throws IOException {
        return createPositionOutputstream();
    }

    private PositionOutputStream createPositionOutputstream() {
        return new PositionOutputStream() {
            
            int pos = 0;

            @Override
            public long getPos() throws IOException {
                return pos;
            }

            @Override
            public void flush() throws IOException {
                out.flush();
            };

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                out.close();
            };

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                out.write(b);
                pos++;
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                out.write(b, off, len);
                pos += len;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public PositionOutputStream createOrOverwrite(long blockSizeHint) throws IOException {
        return createPositionOutputstream();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsBlockSize() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public long defaultBlockSize() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to write the data into temp file and then covert the data from file to input stream or buffer
something like this, first read the tempfile data

```
final InputStream targetStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(tmp1.getAbsoluteFile()));

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
String encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
IOUtils.copy(targetStream, writer, encoding);
System.out.println(writer);
```